# Laravel / encrypt decrypt user table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to encrypt data fields of user table and i don't want to break the the laravel default Auth functionality.

I want something like this

```
DB::table('client')->insertGetId(
        array(
        'name'  =>DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('".$data['name']."', '".env('DB_ENCRYP_KEY')."')"), 
        'email' => DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('".$data['email']."', '".env('DB_ENCRYP_KEY')."')"), 
        'password' => DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('".$data['password']."', '".env('DB_ENCRYP_KEY')."')")

        )

);
```

want to use ASE_ENCRYPT in query level. 
I just need to know where can i find the raw MySQL query for Laravel authentication module. So i can change those query like this. what is the file name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `auth()->attempt()`, query for the user yourself, then use the `login` method.

For example, in your controller's `login` method:

```php
public function login()
{
    $user = User::where(...)->first();

    if ($user) {
        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->intended();
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Wrong credentials');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using the default app created with the `laravel new` command, then you are looking for the create method in [AuthController.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php#L57-L64) (app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php)

The create method is called from the trait [RegistersUsers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L38) wrapped in an Auth::login method, so just be sure to return an instance of your User model instead of just the ID (as with the insertGetId method)